# Adding related entity in asp mvc using Entity Framework and BulkInsert

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, bulkinsert

At the beginning sorry for English abilities. 
I'm new in EF and I encountered a problem. What I have to do is:

---

- One main(parent) entity which store ForeginKeys to other entities(child)
- Insert many rows in one transaction scope.
- Adds child when parent is adding.

For Example:

```
public class Parent()
{
  [Key]
  public int ParentId();

  public int Child_1ID {get; set;}

  public int Child_2ID {get; set;}

  [ForeginKey("Child_1ID")]
  public virtual Child1 Child1 {get; set;}

  [ForeginKey("Child_2ID")]
  public virtual Child2 Child2 {get; set;}
}
```

---

```
public class Child1()
{
    public int Child_1ID {get; set;}

    //some prop
}

public class Child2()
{
    public int Child_2ID {get; set;}

    //some prop
}
```

---

```
public class Action()
{
    using(var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        usig(var ctx = new DbContext())
        { 
            var child1ToInsert = new List<Child1>();
            var child2ToInsert = new List<Child2>();
            var parentToInsert = new List<Partent>();

            while( some condition )
            {
                var child1 = new Child()
                {
                   some prop
                };
                child1ToInsert.Add(child1);

                var child2 = new Child()
                {
                   some prop
                };
                child2ToInsert.Add(child2);

                var parent = new Parent()
                {
                   Child_1ID = child1.Id;     // is right?
                   Child_2ID = child2.Id;
                }
                parentToInsert.Add(parent);
            }

            ctx.BulkInsert(child1ToInsert);
            ctx.BulkInsert(child2ToInsert);
            ctx.BulkInsert(parentToInsert);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            transactionScope.Complete();
        }
    }
```

---

So, I have correctly data, bulkInserts works correctly too but **how to insert right Id's of childrens to parent?** Now after some attempts Id's in db are nulls.

Comment: are you using any extensions for ctx.BulkInsert(child1ToInsert); ?

Comment: yes, I use extension from https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/

Comment: you can't insert this parent child tables at once using this extension.

Comment: this extension is just a wrapper library of writetoserver in sqlbulkcopy which accepts only datatable,datarow and datareader as parameters see the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, so I I should base only on sqlbulkcopy? It necessary for me to keep correctly Id's of children in parent.

Comment: you can use only the methods of sqlbulkcopy which doesn't provide this functionality.SO you have to create the parent's first and then try inserting the child,i know it difficult to manage, but no other way.i also faced this situation in my project